# Creating my first program to display birthday

Tags: c++, c++14

I am creating my first program to display the date of someone's birthday. This is really a beginners thing.

I just wanted to know, how would I display it with the format of MM/DD/YY?

Here is my programming code below. For some reason, when it displays the birthday, it shows a random number. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m,d,y;

    cout << "Please enter your birthday in the format of MM/DD/YY ";
    cin >> m >> d >> y;

    cout << "Your birthday is: " << m << d << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the inputs?

Comment: Presumably any set of three 1- or 2-digit numbers, separated by slashes, @Oblivion.

Answer (score 2):

By entering '/' into d which is expecting int, you are making cin to go into failed state and it ignores any furthur calls to it hence your d and y being auto variables are having garbage value, try to include a char variable seperator in your code to input the field seperating m,d and y.

```
int main() {
  int m, d, y;
  char seperator;


  cout << "Please enter your birthday in the format of MM/DD/YY ";
  cin >> m >> seperator >> d>> seperator >> y;

  cout << "Your birthday is: " << m << seperator << d<< seperator << y << endl;
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much! Yeah I haven't learn the char seperator yet so thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

In addition to manually filtering the separator out as done in [Abdul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58258771/5386374), there are a few other ways we can parse a `MM/DD/YY` string to obtain a date from it.  I'll look at two of them, to give you other things to explore as you learn.

---

The first is to extract the raw data for each part of the date string, and then convert it to `int`.  There are multiple ways to do this, but the simplest is to just use `std::string` and its associated `std::getline()`.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cin, std::cout
#include <string>   // std::string, std::stoi(), std::getline(istream, string).

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Constants.  Could also use const instead of constexpr.
    constexpr char Sep    = '/'; // Field separator.
    constexpr int  Fields = 3;   // Storing field count as a constant for clarity.

    //int m,d,y;
    int mdy[Fields]; // Storing in an array to simplify code.


    cout << "Please enter your birthday in the format of MM/DD/YY ";
    //cin >> m >> d >> y;

    // Extract & parse.  Will be executed 3 times.
    for (int i = 0; i < Fields; i++) {
        string parser;
        getline(cin, parser, Sep); // Pull out everything up to the next Sep or end of stream, then throw away Sep (if present).
        mdy[i] = stoi(parser);     // Convert string to int.
    }

    //cout << "Your birthday is: " << m << d << y << endl;
    cout << "Your birthday is: ";

    // Output data.  Will be executed 3 times.
    for (int i = 0; i < Fields; i++) {
        cout << mdy[i]                           // Output field.
             << (i < (Fields - 1) ? Sep : '\n'); // Output Sep after all but last field, or newline after last field.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will take each part of the date out of `std::cin` as a set of characters, stopping whenever it reaches a `/` or the end of the input.  It then treats the characters as a string containing a number, and takes the number out of it for later use.  It does so using a loop, which will execute 3 (`Fields`) times.  [This is a bit worse than your original code, but makes up for it by cleanly handling the garbage data for you, and being easier to read once you know how it works.  It's also easier to expand later on, if you want to also store, say, hours/minutes/seconds.]

Note that the loops are strictly unnecessary; you could also do this:

```
int m, d, y;
string parser;

// ...

// Extract & parse.
getline(cin, parser, Sep); m = stoi(parser);
getline(cin, parser, Sep); d = stoi(parser);
getline(cin, parser, Sep); y = stoi(parser);

// ...

// Output data.
cout << m << Sep
     << d << Sep
     << y << '\n';
```

It also replaces `std::endl` with newline literal `'\n'`, which is usually preferred over `std::endl`.  [Specifically, `std::endl` outputs `'\n'` and then immediately flushes the stream (actually *outputs* the data).  If you just use `'\n'`, then it'll wait for you to specifically tell it to flush the data, so it can do as much work as possible with a single output operation.  There's no actual difference in this case, but it's a good practice to develop... provided you can tell when you actually *do* want to flush immediately.]

---

The second option is to use facilities intended specifically for handling date and time; this will do your desired task more cleanly, but may not be as good a learning experience.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cin, std::cout
#include <iomanip>  // std::get_time(), std::put_time()
#include <ctime>    // std::tm

using namespace std;

int main() {
    constexpr char Format[] = "%D";
    // Date/time format string, indicating "Date in form MM/DD/YY."
    // Note: Could also use "%m/%d/%y" for same results.

    //int m,d,y;
    tm date;

    cout << "Please enter your birthday in the format of MM/DD/YY ";
    //cin >> m >> d >> y;
    cin >> get_time(&date, Format);

    //cout << "Your birthday is: " << m << d << y << endl;
    cout << "Your birthday is: " << std::put_time(&date, Format) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, we use `std::tm`, a simple `struct` holding date & time information.  Helper functions `std::get_time()` and `std::put_time()` extract and output the stored data, taking a pointer to the `tm` to store data in and a formatting string to indicate what data to get.

Note that `tm` isn't a black box, just a convenient collection of relevant fields.  We can do this manually, but it won't be as clean.

```
cout << "Your birthday is: "
     // Month: Stored as 00..11, so add one.
     << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << date.tm_mon + 1  << '/'
     // Day of the month: Stored as 01..31, so no adjustment.
     << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << date.tm_mday << '/'
     // Year: Stored as years since 1900, so subtract 100 if it's over 99.
     << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (date.tm_year < 100 ? date.tm_year : date.tm_year - 100) << '\n';
```

There isn't really as much room to experiment here, so it's not the best to use while learning.  It's convenient once you know how input and output work, though, since it handles extraction, processing, and insertion for you.

Comment: DAMN LOL I have no clue on what you wrote but I am excited to learn this type of stuff in my college classes, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: Fair enough, @naustin288. ;P  For the basics, `string` is a class for handling consecutive character sequences (strings), the version of `getline()` I used reads characters from a stream until it finds the separator (like using `cin >> c` (where `c` is a `char`) and storing the result in the string, up until it reads the separator into `c` (and throws the separator away)), and `stoi()` is a tool to get an integer out of a string.  I'd suggest reading something like [this C++ string tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html), you may find it helpful.

Comment: Arrays (`int mdy[]`) are simple, consecutive collections of items, accessed by the array's name and an index number (`int mdy[]` is three `int`s in a row, `mdy[0]`, `mdy[1]`, and `mdy[2]`; the first element is `0`, not `1`, mainly for historical reasons).  They're a bit more complex than normal variables, but not that hard to get the hang of.  Loops are just a way of telling the compiler that you want the code to run multiple times in a row, until a certain condition is met (in this case, loops three times, with a condition variable storing `0`, `1`, and `2`).

Comment: The two are often used together, with a `for` loop used to apply the code to elements of an array.  The loop's condition will be based on the array's index, as shown here (e.g., for an array with 3 elements, we use a variable that starts as 0 and increases by 1 on each run through the loop, and make the loop run until the variable hits 3).

Comment: `constexpr` is a bit more advanced; when used on variables (like here), it's a keyword that means "this is `const`, and known at compile time; hard-code if possible, please".  In most cases, `constexpr` variables will be directly replaced with their contents, because the compiler will read and use the variable while compiling your code instead of leaving it for the code to use itself (e.g., the compiler will turn `int mdy[Fields]` into `int mdy[3]`, and `getline(cin, parser, Sep)` into `getline(cin, parser, '/')`). It's a bit like a better `#define` macro, if you've learned about them already.

Comment: `Format` is a C string (`char` array).  Specifically, since it's a string literal (hard-coded string), it's a `const` array (`const char Format[]`); in this case, `constexpr` implies `const`, so I don't need to repeat anything.  It's three characters long, rather than the two you see; C strings end with a null character ('\0'), so the literal itself is `const char[3] { '%', 'D', '\0' }`.  You'll likely find yourself working with `std::string`s more than C strings.

Comment: And for something less basic... `tm`, `get_time()`, and `put_time()` are used for working with time and dates.  They exactly solve your problem, and do exactly what you want your code to do, but aren't as useful a learning tool because they don't give you as much room to experiment.